# Error of syncronism in sending data from a file using a pipe

Tags: c, pipe, readfile

I have done this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 255
#define PATH "./test.txt"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char read_msg[BUFFER_SIZE];
    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    fp = fopen(PATH, "r");
    int fd[2];
    pid_t pid;
    if(pipe(fd) == -1){
        perror("Pipe failed");
        return 1;
    }

    pid=fork();
    if (pid==-1)
    {
        perror("Fork failed");
        return 1;
    }

    if (pid>0)
    {
        close(fd[0]);
        fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, (FILE*)fp);
        do{
            write(fd[1],buffer,strlen(buffer)+1); 
            //sleep(1);
        }while(fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, (FILE*)fp) != NULL);
    close(fd[1]);
    wait(NULL);
}else{
    close(fd[1]);
    while(read(fd[0], read_msg, BUFFER_SIZE) != 0){
    printf("Child had read: %s", read_msg);
    } 
    close(fd[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code must create a pipe between the father process and the child process.
The father process must read the file and send each line to the child process.
The child process prints the received lines.

But this code have some error.
If I run like this I get only some lines of the text in the file.
If I run using the commented sleep(1) I get all lines of the text.

Can anyone see the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems.

Here:

```
write(fd[1],buffer,strlen(buffer)+1);
```

you're writing the terminating null to the file. When you call `read()`, if there are multiple lines available, it will read them all into your buffer, but when you then `printf()` them, it'll only print up to the first terminating null, so you never see them any of the lines after the first one. Adding your `sleep()` call prevents more than one line being written to the file before the other process has a chance to `read()`, so the problem doesn't manifest in that case.

Solution: don't write the terminating null to your text file. At the same time, you can make your code a little more compact by changing:

```
fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, (FILE*)fp);
do{
    write(fd[1],buffer,strlen(buffer)+1); 
}while(fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, (FILE*)fp) != NULL);
```

to:

```
while ( fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, fp) ) {
     write(fd[1], buffer, strlen(buffer));
}
```

Second, `read()` doesn't null terminate your string for you, so when you implement this solution, this call:

```
read(fd[0], read_msg, BUFFER_SIZE)
```

will not null-terminate `read_msg`. The solution is to check how many bytes `read()` actually read, and manually add the terminating null after that many bytes. Note that you will need to read at most one byte less than the buffer size, in case you fill it up, since you'll need room for the terminating null.

Other comments:

1. You don't check whether `fopen()` succeeds, and you should. Same thing for `write()` and `close()`. You do a good job checking the return values in other cases.
2. The cast to `FILE *` in `fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, (FILE*)fp)` has no effect since `fp` is already of type `FILE *`. It should be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139470/program-that-read-file-and-send-it-to-parent-process-with-pipe)'s accepted answer for a good explanation of why using fgets here can cause issues.

You can take the following approach in the parent:

```
   if (pid>0)
{
    int size, file_fd;
    file_fd = fileno(fp);

    close(fd[0]);
    while((size = read(file_fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE)) != 0) {
        write(fd[1],buffer,size); 
        //sleep(1);
    }
close(fd[1]);
wait(NULL);
}
```

And in the child:

```
else{
    close(fd[1]);
    int size;
    while((size = read(fd[0], read_msg, BUFFER_SIZE)) != 0){
        write(1,read_msg, size);
    } 
    close(fd[0]);
    }
    fflush(stdout);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Which reads in chunks. Note that I replaced:

```
printf("Child had read: %s", read_msg);
```

For consistency since we're using lower-level system calls, and things can get tricky when you mix-up buffered I/O like printf with system calls.

There are also some other more minor issues (e.g. you don't close the parent file), and you should run many more checks when reading/writing to verify there hasn't been an error, but this gets to the heart of your issue.